# Eclipse creates snippet package when pasting code into Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, code-snippets

When pasting a the code of a class into the Project Explorer of Eclipse, the code is pasted into the selected source Folder inside the correct package.

But when there is a comment above the package declaration (version-control...), the comment is pasted as a Snippet inside a newly created Snippet package. Also the comment is then missing inside the newly pasted class.

How can I prevent Eclipse from doing that?

Comment: Find the Java code which does this, improve it to handle leading comments and do a pull request [here](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui).